# Can't PsPing to Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, sysinternals

I know that ping'ing into Azure VMs is disabled. The following page shows how to use Sysinternals' PsPing to do a TCP-based ping:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/

Unfortunately, I cannot get PsPing to work from my premises to the Azure VM I have.  I created an inbound rule in the Network Security Group through the Azure portal:

[image]

My Azure VM is a Windows 2012 Datacenter server.  I added the following rule to its firewall:

[image]

Nevertheless, I can't get PsPing to work when targeting port 80.  Incidentally, PsPing to port 3389 (the RDP port) works.

What else should I try?

Comment: You could install `telnet` on your VM, `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`, could it succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check whether your port is listening. According to your description, it seems that port 80 is not listening on your VM. You could use the following command to check.

```
netstat -ant|findstr 80
```

Please ensure the port 80 is listening on tcp, the result should be like below:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
```

Also, you should check your NSG. NSG could be associated to a subnet or a VM nic.

Comment: Walter, a huge Thank You! As you guessed correctly, there was no listener, so instead of fiddling w/ IIS, I downloaded and ran Mongoose, and it worked. Much appreciated.